# find a value from array of object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
temp = [
  {
    date: "31/2/12",
    description: "A",
  },
  {
    date: "31/2/12",
    description: "c",
  },
  {
    date: "31/2/12",
    description: "b",
  },
];
```

mongo query should return date if description=A or description =B

Comment: You can do like https://mongoplayground.net/p/p3Jd8HkYxvx

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate pipeline using `$or` into `$filter` to get your desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "temp": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$temp",
          "cond": {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$eq": ["$$this.description","A"]
              },
              {
                "$eq": ["$$this.description","B"]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g9UfOgiyXNc) where `B` is not returned because is in lower case. If you want a query case insensitive you can use `$regexMatch` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D711rkjyj-d) where `i` is the option **i**nsensitive-case.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "temp": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$temp",
          "cond": {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$$this.description",
                  "regex": "a",
                  "options": "i"
                }
              },
              {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$$this.description",
                  "regex": "b",
                  "options": "i"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Or also, you can use your "or" into the regex directly using `a|b`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "temp": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$temp",
          "cond": {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$$this.description",
              "regex": "a|b",
              "options": "i"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GBqeXcaahbd).

I really don't know which option has better performance.

And, at least, if you want to return only `date` field you can use `$project` stage like this:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "temp.description": 1
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CSQLHExw4k4)